# Hidden Nodes from neural network classifier in PRTools

Tags: neural-network, classification, matlab, pattern-recognition

I am using PRtools back-propagation based feed forward neural network classifier (e.g.[W, HIST]=bpxnc(Dataset,5,inf,[])). I am trying to figure out if we can specify how many nodes each layer has or if there is a way to specify the number of nodes for my classifier?

Thanks for help,
Sabin

Answer (score 0):

Check [PRTools manual](http://rduin.nl/manual/).

```
[W,HIST] = BPXNC (A,UNITS,ITER,W_INI,T,FID)
```

UNITS    Array indicating number of units in each hidden layer (default: [5])

Comment: Thanks Chris. But I was wondering about number of nodes in each layers.

Comment: Based on the description of BPXNC in the PRTools manual I guess UNITS is a vector. The length of the vector determines the number of hidden layers and each value of the vector determines the number of nodes on the corresponding hidden layer.